# Automatically convert xls files to xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, automation

I have a software that just allows me to download my data in xls files but I want to use it as an xlsx file.

Currently I have an excel macro when I click on a button it converts all my xls files in xlsx but I want to automate this task so I don't have to open the excel file and click on the button.

I was thinking of a script that start when I log in windows or something like that, and it converts automatically my xls file when I download it. But I'm not very good with scripts so anyone can help me with that ? It's on windows 7 and 10.

Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

Here is my Powershell script, now I have to automate it so that it runs automatically when I download a new .xls file, I know I can use the task scheduler but how can I do that automation on en event like adding a new xls file to a folder ? Or maybe we can do it in powershell ?

My script:

```
$xlFixedFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlOpenXMLWorkbook
write-host $xlFixedFormat
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false
$folderpath = "C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads\"
$filetype ="*xls"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folderpath -Include $filetype -recurse | 
ForEach-Object `
{
    $path = ($_.fullname).substring(0, ($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
    
    "Converting $path"
    $workbook = $excel.workbooks.open($_.fullname)

    $path += ".xlsx"
    $workbook.saveas($path, $xlFixedFormat)
    $workbook.close()
    
    remove-item $_.fullname
    
}
$excel.Quit()
$excel = $null
[gc]::collect()
[gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

**UPDATE:**

I changed my script to have a new script faster and I put a watcher so I run the script when a new xls file is downloaded, I will use task manager to run this script when I log in windows so it can watch without doing anything.

Here is my new script:

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads"
    $watcher.Filter = "*.xls"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 
                $watcher.Path *.xls | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "xlsx") }
              }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action
    while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

**Issue:**

My script run in the ISE but when i want to run it in cmd or with the right click on my script file and run with with powershell I have this issue

> You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '*' operator.

Comment: What's the reason you want to convert the files? .xls files are still working fine and there is no need to bulk convert them to .xlsx. Why don't you convert them as you open them over time? If you never open them, chances are you don't need them, anyway. Other than that, not being very good with scripts does not get you a ticket for a free script here. If you show your efforts and have a question or are stuck, then post your code and you will get help.

Comment: @teylyn I need to convert the files to use them with a label software so I can print the data, but the software doesn't recognize the xls files when I want to import data. My goal is to gain time because i do this task many times during the day so i don't want to open every files to save them in xlsx it will take me too much time, if I can automate this task it will be great.

Comment: So, what have you tried? A simple search for what you want to do has lots of results with code.

Comment: @teylyn post edited, can you help me with the automatically run the script when I download an .xls file ?

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. This started out as a VBA question, but now you're using PowerShell. I see that the script simply renames the file to a new file extension. I'm not sure if that is sufficient, since xlsx is a totally different internal format than xls.  The first version of the script opened the file in Excel, then saved it in the new file format.  That would definitely be the preferred way, but I dont know PowerShell. You'll need to wait for PowerShell expertise to help you out here.

Comment: For the OP, look into `Workbook.SaveCopyAs` @teylyn `What's the reason you want to convert the files?` an overabundance of paranoia makes me convert or delete every .xls because they may have macros.  I have macros disabled unless signed - but I still change the Trust Center to disable all macros before opening an .xls   The first thing I do is Alt+F11 and comment out any code.  I convert it to .xlsx if I need the file but the code does not impress, if I am impressed then I save an .xlsx and an .xlsm, otherwise it goes to the Recycle Bin.  It may be overkill but I sleep better at night.

Answer (score 0):

The below script automatically runs each morning with Task Manager

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO

    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher

    $watcher.Path = "C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads"

    #$watcher.Filter = "*.*"

    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true



### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED

    $action = { 

                Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Mgtspare\Downloads *.xls | rename-item -newname { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, "xlsx") }

              }

              

### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 

    Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -SourceIdentifier 'FileCreated' -Action $action

    while ($true) {sleep 1000}
```